# jquery Overlay div containing a link over another div containing a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains a link.

At the bottom right corner of this div I have an overlay element which take over the whole div when hovered.

This overlay element also contains a link.

My problem is that the link in the overlying element is not clickable.

Here is my code :

```
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -320px;
  bottom: -320px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4);
}

.overlay-content {
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover~.overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

<div class="panel panel-default1">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel body -->

</div>
<!-- panel default -->
```

I know the issue comes from `pointer-events: none;` in class `.overlay-content`. However, if I get rid of it, both links become unclickable.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y2auh7gn/

Is there any way to make this work ?

Comment: why are setting `pointer-event: none;`. any specific reason?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Hi, if I don't have it, the first link becomes unclickable too, and the corner does not spread on hover anymore.